# How to prevent the browser from killing the Flash plugin while debugging

Tags: actionscript-3, firefox, browser

When I am debugging broken code, after a while the browser announces that the Flash plugin has crashed, and I can't continue debugging my code. Can I prevent the browser from killing Flash?

I am using Firefox.

Comment: I've been having the same problem. I fix it by never debugging humongous blocks of code at once. However, I haven't noticed the issue in FF8, so maybe you should try upgrading

Comment: @PranavHosangadi me too uses the same browser but crashes.

Answer (score 6):

Going to the debugger on a breakpoint makes the plugin "freeze". This is intentional, it's a breakpoint after all!
However, from the browsers perspective, the plugin seems to be stuck in some kind of infinite loop. The timeout value varies, my Firefox installation is set to 45 seconds.

To change the timeout value go enter `about:config` in the url field and look for the setting `dom.ipc.plugins.timeoutSecs` increase this or set it to `-1` to disable the timeout altogether.

Comment: Good insight, but I have to say that the term "debugging broken code" in the question _is_ confusing - I'll be glad to remove my answer, but if it was you who down voted, I'd appreciated an undo.

Comment: +1 to you Wow it works, can u explain what kind of infinite loop in it.

Answer (score -1):

When the plugin crashes, it does in fact not so, because the browser is "killing" it, but rather the plugin terminates itself when a fatal error occurs. This is necessary to prevent the browser, or even your entire machine from crashing - there is no way to tell what is going to happen after an error like that.  And besides: After the first uncaught error, your program will likely not be able to perform even correct code the way you intended, so you won't do any good by continuing a broken debugging session.  So it is not a flaw, it is actually a good thing this happens!

However, you **can** do some things in order to work more effectively (and make your programs better).  The most important I can think of right now are:

- Learn to use good [object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) techniques and get acquainted with [design patterns](http://www.as3dp.com/), if you haven't already done so.
- Take extra care to prevent error conditions from happening (e.g. test if an object is `null` before accessing its properties, give default values to variables when possible, etc.)
- Use proper [error handling](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=11_Handling_errors_04.html) to gracefully catch errors at runtime.
- Use [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) to thoroughly test your code for errors one piece at a time, **before** debugging in the browser. Getting to know [FlexUnit](http://elromdesign.com/blog/2010/03/10/test-driven-development-tdd-with-flexunit-4-complete-tutorial/) is a good place to start.

**EDIT**

I should also have said this: A Debugger is a useful tool for stepping through your code to find the **source** of an error, such as a variable not being properly initialized, or unexpected return values.  It is not helpful when trying to find out what's happening **after** a fatal error has occurred - which will also not help you to fix the code.